# Omnet++ & SUMO: apply transmit power based in Omnetpp based on ID in SUMO in .ini

Tags: pattern-matching, omnet++, sumo

Currently, I am finding a way to set transmit power for vehicles based on the id in .rou.xml file of SUMO.

My .rou.xml file is something like:

```
<vehicle id="pl_a1" type="platoonLeader" route="route0" depart="0" departLane="0" departSpeed="max"/> <!--[0]-->
<vehicle id="ll_a1" type="laneLeader" route="route0" depart="0" departLane="1" departSpeed="max"/> <!--[1]-->
<vehicle id="pl_c1" type="platoonLeader" route="route0" depart="0" departLane="4" departSpeed="max"/> <!--[2]-->
<vehicle id="ll_c1" type="laneLeader" route="route0" depart="0" departLane="5" departSpeed="max"/> <!--[3]-->
<vehicle id="m1_a1" type="member" route="route0" depart="2" departLane="0" departSpeed="max"/> <!--and so on...-->
<vehicle id="m3_a1" type="member" route="route0" depart="2" departLane="1" departSpeed="max"/>
<vehicle id="m1_c1" type="member" route="route0" depart="2" departLane="4" departSpeed="max"/>
<vehicle id="m3_c1" type="member" route="route0" depart="2" departLane="5" departSpeed="max"/>
<vehicle id="m2_a1" type="member" route="route0" depart="4" departLane="0" departSpeed="max"/>
...
```

Which includes 138 vehicles.
In .ini file of Omnetppp, each vehicle is numberred as 0 1 ... based on the order in the .rou.xml file. My way of setting Transmit Power is:

```
*.node[0].wlan[*].radio.transmitter.power = 200mW
```

I have been reading section 10.3 in [this manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#cha:config-sim). However, besides using range [] or {} of number, I have found a way assign transmit power to vehicles with pattern in .rou.xml.

**How can I set a specific amount of transmit power for certain vehicles?**
For example: vehicles with id (in .rou.xml) pattern as `pl_*` will have 200mW, vehicles with pattern `m1_*` will have transmit power of 0.2mW.